# 429 Error in Load Testing ( Apache Jmeter)

Tags: testing, jmeter, load

I am getting 429 error ( Too Many Requests) when I am using only 1 user to send just 1 request.
Can somebody give a suggestion on this?

Answer (score 0):

It might be connected with your (or your [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address)) previous/current activity, for example if you're behind [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)

You can try out changing your [IP address](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-ip-spoofing-simulate-requests-different-ip-addresses-jmeter/) by specifying a different one, the setting lives under Advanced tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

[image]

If this doesn't help you can try running your test from another machine, i.e. kick off a cloud-based virtual machine in [AWS Free Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) or [Oracle Cloud Free Tier](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/) or JMeter cloud services like [BlazeMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/) or [RedLine13](https://www.redline13.com/blog/)